# Obj-c - App crashing if tableview section is empty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using the below code to alphabetically organize my tableView. The filter works correctly, however if one of the sections contains no results (ie. There's nothing returned for the letter "A"), it causes my app to crash, as the tableView is trying to populate a cell with data that isn't there. Any idea how I can prevent this?

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
                [super viewDidLoad];
                
 self.clientSections = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"#", @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", @"g", @"h", @"i", @"j", @"k", @"l", @"m", @"n", @"o", @"p", @"q", @"r", @"s", @"t", @"u", @"v", @"w", @"x", @"y", @"z", nil];
    
    
 NSMutableDictionary *viewParams1 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [viewParams1 setValue:@"cdata" forKey:@"view_name"];
        [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams1 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            
            self.clients = [responseObject mutableCopy];
          
            
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"last name" ascending:YES];
    
self.clientsAZ = [self.clients sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
            
    
               } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];
        
            
           -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    
        
        return [self.clientSections count];
        
    }
    
    - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
          return self.clientSections;
    }
    
    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     
        return [self.clientSections objectAtIndex:section];
      
        
    }
            
            
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            
                
 self.finalfiltered = [self.clientsAZ  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K beginswith[cd] %@)", @"last name", [self.clientSections objectAtIndex:section]]];
                    
                
                    return [self.finalfiltered count];
                 
            }
            
    
            -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
                
               
                    static NSString *ClientTableIdentifier = @"ClientTableViewCell";
                    
                    ClientTableViewCell *cell = (ClientTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ClientTableIdentifier];
                    
                    if (cell == nil)
                    {
                        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ClientTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
                        
                    }
                   
                
                NSString *photo = [self.finalfiltered valueForKey:@"client photo"][indexPath.row];
                 
                NSString *first = [self.finalfiltered valueForKey:@"first name"][indexPath.row];
                   
                NSString *last = [self.finalfiltered valueForKey:@"last name"][indexPath.row];
                  
                NSString *telephone = [self.finalfiltered valueForKey:@"phone"][indexPath.row];
                  
                NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", first, last];
              
                cell.clientName.text = fullName;
                cell.subtext.text = telephone;
                    
                NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:photo];
                NSLog(@"The photo url is %@", photo);
                [cell.clientPhoto setImageWithURL:imageUrl];
                    
                    return cell;
                    
                    
                    }
                    
                    
              }
```

**Edit:** **Here's what is returned when I log self.finalfiltered.** Note, I'm sorting by last name. Order appears to be correct.

```
2021-02-10 16:53:34.905601-0800 [1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.905846-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.906076-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.906335-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.906566-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.906772-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.907025-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.907558-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.907772-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.908296-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
        {
        body = none;
        city = Victoria;
        "client photo" = "/stockphotos/person5.png";
        country = Canada;
        email = "thomas.ingram@outlook.com";
        "first name" = Thomas;
        "last name" = Ingram;
        "mailing address" = "502 Catherine Street";
        "mailing address 2" = "Apt 403";
        nid = 127;
        "node_title" = "Thomas Ingram";
        notes = "test notes";
        phone = "250-998-0389";
        scheduleddate = "Feb 8 2021 1:00 PM";
        scheduledtime = none;

        "state or province" = BC;
        "zip code" = "V9A 3T3";
    }
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.908833-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
        {
        body = none;
        city = Toronto;
        "client photo" = "/stockphotos/person2.png";
        country = Canada;
        email = "andrea@gmail.com";
        "first name" = Andrea;
        "last name" = Johnson;
        "mailing address" = "227 Willow Avenue";
        "mailing address 2" = "Unit 2034";
        nid = 124;
        "node_title" = "Andrea Johnson";
        notes = "test notes";
        phone = "416-223-2397";
        scheduleddate = "Feb 8 2021 07:00 PM";
        scheduledtime = "5:45 PM";
        "state or province" = ON;
        "zip code" = "M5M 1W4";
    }
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.909541-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
        {
        body = none;
        city = Burnaby;
        "client photo" = "/sites/default/files/stored/1612926759.jpg";
        country = Canada;
        email = email@email.com;
        "first name" = Cody;
        "last name" = Lin;
        "mailing address" = "4036 Pandora Street";
        "mailing address 2" = "-";
        nid = 171;
        "node_title" = "Cody Lin”;
        notes = "test notes”;
        phone = "604-250-7422";
        scheduleddate = none;
        scheduledtime = none;
        "state or province" = BC;
        "zip code" = V5C2A9;
    }
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.910439-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
        {
        body = none;
        city = "New York City";
        "client photo" = "/stockphotos/person4.png";
        country = US;
        email = "mlevy39@gmail.com";
        "first name" = Michael;
        "last name" = Levy;
        "mailing address" = "22 Lexington Avenue";
        "mailing address 2" = "Apt 102";
        nid = 126;
        "node_title" = "Michael Levy";
        notes = "test notes";
        phone = "212-983-0029";
        scheduleddate = "Feb 10 2021 1:00 PM";
        scheduledtime = none;
        "state or province" = NY;
        "zip code" = 90020;
    },
        {
        body = none;
        city = London;
        "client photo" = "/stockphotos/person1.png";
        country = Canada;
        email = "janinejlohr@gmail.com";
        "first name" = Janine;
        "last name" = Monroe;
        "mailing address" = "909 Fake Street";
        "mailing address 2" = "Unit 4103";
        nid = 123;
        "node_title" = "Janine Monroe";
        notes = "test notes";
        phone = "778-028-2938";
        scheduleddate = "Feb 14 2021 7:37 PM, Feb 17 2021 9:00 AM";
        scheduledtime = none;
        "state or province" = BC;
        "zip code" = "V6E 4V2";
    }
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.911207-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.911423-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.911630-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.911834-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.912033-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.912233-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.912431-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.913457-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.913671-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.913931-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.914378-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
        {
        body = none;
        city = Vancouver;
        "client photo" = "/stockphotos/person3.png";
        country = Canada;
        email = "cali.wright@gmail.com";
        "first name" = Cali;
        "last name" = Wright;
        "mailing address" = "667 Fake Street";
        "mailing address 2" = "Apt 4102";
        nid = 125;
        "node_title" = "Cali Wright";
        notes = "test notes”;
        phone = "778-867-7184";
        scheduleddate = none;
        scheduledtime = none;
        "state or province" = BC;
        "zip code" = none;
    }
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.914652-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
2021-02-10 16:53:34.914868-0800 -[1784:532468] THE FINAL FILTER (
)
```

**The crash that occurs is:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
```

**And lastly, in the code, it seems to crash right before this line:**

```
 NSString *photo = [self.finalfiltered valueForKey:@"client photo"][indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Do you know on which line it crashes?

Comment: Literally right before :  NSString *photo = [self.finalfiltered valueForKey:@"client photo"][indexPath.row]; @jnpdx And when I mute out the population of the cell's data and just log self.finalfiltered, the organized array is populated as it should be.

Comment: Can you amend your question with what the log says `finalfiltered` is and what row it crashes on (ie what the debugger says `indexPath.row` is at the time of the crash)?

Comment: See updated above @jnpdx!

Comment: I'm not going to leave an "answer" so that the question remains open and it'll get more attention, but the error is very clear about what's happening - the array `[self.finalfiltered valueForKey:@"client photo"]` is empty, but you're asking it to return something for row `0`. This means that there's a mismatch between your code in `numberOfRows...` and the actual number of rows you have in one of the arrays. Also, it concerns me to be setting a property like `finalfiltered` in `numberOfRows...` in case the system asks for things out-of-order, which may be happening here.

Comment: @jnpdx Doesn't it have to be set there in order to use [self.clientSections objectAtIndex:section] ? Also, the client photo key isn't empty for any of the returned results - if it was, it would also crash prior to me sorting the array of dictionaries? The crash still occurs even when I remove the client photo line.

Comment: It isn't legal to have an empty section in a tableview. You either need to return a correct value from `numberOfSections` that indicates the number of non-empty sections or in `cellForRow` check that the section is empty an return a placeholder cell.

Comment: Super confused as to how I can do this with my above code. Example? @Paulw11

Comment: I was under the impression that this line was grabbing the specific number of rows in each section:  self.finalfiltered = [self.clients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K beginswith[cd] %@)", @"last name", [self.clientSections objectAtIndex:section]]]; -- I'm just not sure how to handle an empty section?

Comment: Yes, it is, but in some cases it will return 0 rows.  This isn't permitted. It is very inefficient to filter your data in `numberOfRowsInSection`.  You should create a filter function that produces two arrays - An array of "first letters" (Including an entry for digits - # - if required) and an array of arrays of clients.  Then you can return the array of first letters as your section index titles, the count of this array as your number of sections and the count of the relevant element of your array of client arrays as your number of rows.

Comment: Using this approach you will only see a section index for letters that actually exist in your data (Say, "A", "C","S") not A-Z.  If you want to always show A-Z then you need to implement an appropriate `sectionForSectionIndexTitle` - e.g. if someone taps "B" and there is no B you either return 0 (A) or (1) C depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @Paulw11 That is exactly what I've done. self.clientSections is my array of letters, and self.clients is the array of clients (both are created in viewDidLoad). The array of letters is currently set as my headers, and the count of the letters array does provide the number of sections. What I'm missing is the count of rows for each section. The only reason I'm filtering in numberOfRowsInSection is because I'm not sure how to grab the row count :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228562/discussion-between-paulw11-and-brittany).

Comment: See updated above @Paulw11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is to always return `27` for the number of sections in your tableview, corresponding to digits and the letters A-Z.  However, a `UITableView` cannot have a section with 0 rows.  This means you have a problem when your data doesn't contain a last name starting with "b", for example; You return 0 for section 1, but this isn't allowed.  The tableview still requests row 0 for the empty section and you get an array bounds exception.

For the purposes of an answer I have simplified your cell display code a little, since I didn't want to fully populate all of the data fields and set up a custom cell (You should really use an object to encapsulate your data model rather than a dictionary too).

Most of the work is done in the method `splitClients` - This creates the appropriate arrays for each section and the section titles.  In this code I ensured that the data was created in sorted order, but you can sort the data as you do in your code.

By creating the right arrays you can see how much simpler `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` are - You want these functions, along with `cellForRowAt` to be efficient as they will be called numerous times as the table view scrolls.

The other method of note is `sectionForSectionIndexTitle` - Since not all of the index sections may be populated, this function is used to return the closest populated section, so if you select "b" and there are no "b"s, it will scroll to "c".

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property NSArray<NSDictionary *> *clients;
@property NSArray<NSArray *> *sectionClients;
@property NSArray<NSString *> *sectionLetters;
@property NSArray<NSString *> *sectionHeaders;
@property IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sectionLetters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"#", @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", @"g", @"h", @"i", @"j", @"k", @"l", @"m", @"n", @"o", @"p", @"q", @"r", @"s", @"t", @"u", @"v", @"w", @"x", @"y", @"z", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    NSMutableArray *clients = [NSMutableArray new];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"Andrew" lastName:@"67Anderson"]];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"Andrew" lastName:@"Anderson"]];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"Zaphod" lastName:@"Beeblebrox"]];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"Bob" lastName:@"Carlson"]];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"David" lastName:@"Carlson"]];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"Anthony" lastName:@"Edwards"]];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"Griff" lastName:@"Jones"]];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"Sara" lastName:@"Kelly"]];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"Mabel" lastName:@"Maloney"]];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"Horatio" lastName:@"Newton"]];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"Josie" lastName:@"Peters"]];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"Mel" lastName:@"Smith"]];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"Michael" lastName:@"Taylor"]];
    [clients addObject:[self clientWithFirstname:@"Mary" lastName:@"Zax"]];
    
    self.clients = [clients copy];
    
    [self splitClients];
    NSLog(@"Done splitting");
}

-(NSDictionary *)clientWithFirstname:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    dict[@"first name"] = firstName;
    dict[@"last name"] = lastName;
    return dict;
}

-(void)splitClients {
    
    NSMutableArray *sectionClients = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray *sectionHeaders = [NSMutableArray new];
    
    // Look for last names that start with a digit using a regex

    NSArray *digitClients = [self.clients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K MATCHES %@)",@"last name",@"[0-9].*" ]];
    
    // Add a section for digit names if any were found

    if ([digitClients count] > 0) {
        [sectionClients addObject:digitClients];
        [sectionHeaders addObject:@"#"];
    }
    
    // Now check for names starting with each letter of the alphabet

    for (NSString *letter in self.sectionLetters) {
        
        NSArray *letterArray = [self.clients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K beginswith[cd] %@)", @"last name",letter]];

        // If any matching names were found, add them as a new section

        if ([letterArray count] >0) {
            [sectionClients addObject:letterArray];
            [sectionHeaders addObject:letter];
        }
    }
    
    self.sectionClients = [sectionClients copy];
    self.sectionHeaders = [sectionHeaders copy];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.sectionClients count];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.sectionLetters;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    return self.sectionHeaders[section];
 
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.sectionClients[section] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title
               atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    
    NSInteger targetSection = 0;
    
    for (NSString *letter in self.sectionHeaders) {
        NSComparisonResult result = [title compare:letter];
        // If the section index is >= the target index, break and exit
        if (result == NSOrderedAscending || result == NSOrderedSame) {
            break;
        }
        // Otherwise increment the section number
        targetSection++;
    }
    
    return targetSection;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    NSDictionary *client = self.sectionClients[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", client[@"first name"], client[@"last name"]];
    
    return cell;
    
}

@end
```

Comment: You are...a wizard. This worked so flawlessly, I want to upvote it 500000 times. Thank you so, so much.